# Hashtables in llvm using ocaml

Tags: ocaml, llvm

I'm working on a toy programming language/compiler using ocaml and its llvm bindings. I want to have hashtables/hashmaps as a built in data structure for my language however I'm confused as to how to go about them.

I know the llvm c++ api has an ADT directory with a bunch of data structures that would suffice my needs, but I don't know how to call them using the ocaml api.

Another option would be to implement them using c and link them but I would rather focus on the first idea.

It would be helpful if anyone has useful resources on how to use/implement these data structures in llvm (either through the ocaml bindings or directly using the IR, not the c++ api).

Comment: The data structures in the ADT directory are meant to be used by the tools that use the LLVM API, not by the code generated by them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know the llvm c++ api has an ADT directory with a bunch of data structures that would suffice my needs, but I don't know how to call them using the ocaml api.

You can't call them from the OCaml API, but even if you could, they wouldn't solve your problem. They're just data structures, not a way to generate LLVM code. If you could use them in OCaml, you'd have a couple of additional options of data structures you could use in addition to OCaml's built-in lists, maps, sets and arrays. You wouldn't have a way to generate LLVM code implementing these data structures. That's not what the classes do.

Those data structures could just as well be a separate library that has nothing to do with LLVM. They're part of LLVM because they're used by the LLVM project, not because they're directly related to generating LLVM code.

> Another option would be to implement them using c and link them but I would rather focus on the first idea.

That or linking against an existing library implementing hashtables (with added glue code to make them work with your language's type system and memory model as appropriate) would be your only options.